# How to truncate a TextView leaving certain number of characters at the end of the text view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, textview, android-developer-api

I have a TextView where I set a text ( for eg: **Aaron Taylor Johnson [Participant]** ). The TextView should truncate, where [Participants] should be present even after truncation.Something like this:

**Aaron Taylor Jo...[Participant]**

**Aaron Tay...[Participant]**

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: have you checked ellipse attribute of TextView. Check this [link](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/03/android-how-to-display-ellipse-in.html)

Comment: you can use two textview and first one you can use truncation and second one just remain same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using xml attribute of the textView as following.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="An example"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can use TextView attribute android:ellipsize="middle" but it won't solve your problem as it would truncate it in the middle of text, it doesn't matter if it's cutting [Participant] name too.

What you need is two TextView in a single LinearLayout, 1st TextView is for general text and 2nd is for participant name.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ips sdafjdskafj kdlsajf kljds gfsad fsda "
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Participant"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check

```
if (textview.getText().toString().contains([Participant]))
{
String str = textview.getText().toString() ; 
textview.setText(str.subString(1,k)+"...[Participant]") ; 
}
```

Where k is the length of the starting string you want in your textView.